# Cannot get special price

Tags: magento2.3, price, special-price

I have the following problem:

I want to get the final price programatically but it always displays 0

I tried with :

```
$product->getSpecialPrice();

$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice("final_price")->getValue();
```

both displays 0

On the other hand `$product->getPrice()` displays the normal regular price correctly

Is there an other way to get the special price?

I get the products like this:

```
$collection = $block->getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array('in' => $alle_skus) )
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->load();
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to create $product object?

Comment: actually i got the answer. `$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice("final_price")->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();`

Comment: No not this one. $product object creation code?

Comment: @SukumarGorai let me see

Comment: @SukumarGorai i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

> **Get product special price**

```
// get product regular price
$prd_regular_pice = $product->getPrice();

//get product final price
$prd_final_pice = $product->getFinalPrice(); // special price 

if($prd_regular_pice != $prd_final_pice) {
    $special price = $prd_final_pice;
} else {
    $special price = "No Special Price"
}
// get special price

echo  "Special Price  ".$special price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` to get Special Price.

To get the special price you can do it a couple of ways, this one being by product ID:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository */
$this->_productRepository = $productRepository;

$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id); <-- get the product by product ID
return $product->getSpecialPrice();
```

Or you can do by product SKU:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository */
$this->_productRepository = $productRepository;

$product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku); <!-- get the product by product SKU
return $product->getSpecialPrice();
```